# Replace an int with a string in a numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array as follows:

```
board = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
```

I would like to replace a value in the array, for example:

```
board[1, 2] = 'x'.
```

But as I understand, I cannot do this as the array is in type int and what I am trying to replace it with is a string. When I run this, I get the error:

*ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'*

I tried setting the dtype of the array to str:

```
board = np.arange(9, dtype=str).reshape(3, 3)
```

But this gives me the error:

*ValueError: no fill-function for data-type.*

Thanks

Comment: try to cast the int array to a string array after the initialization as follows: `np.arange(9).astype(np.str).reshape(3, 3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `numpy` any non-numeric `dtype` is of type `object`.

This will work:

```
board = np.arange(9, dtype=object).reshape(3, 3)
board[1, 2] = 'x'
```

Cheers.